# How to Convert ImageSource to byte[]?

Tags: silverlight

I try to find in google how to convert imageSource to byte[] - and i can't find the why to do it.

Someone can help here ?

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert ImageSource to Byte array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26814426/how-to-convert-imagesource-to-byte-array)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a BitmapSource you can use [BitmapSource.CopyPixels Method (Array, Int32, Int32)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms616043.aspx)

Or alternativeley, for example if you need a ARGB byte sequence:

```
var bmp = new WriteableBitmap((BitmapSource)source);
byte[] pixels = bmp.Pixels.SelectMany(p => new byte[]
{
    (byte)p,
    (byte)(p >> 8),
    (byte)(p >> 16),
    (byte)(p >> 24)
}).ToArray();
```